# Filling a 2D array with 0s in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I've been trying to fill up a 2D array with JavaScript and I keep crashing my browser so I assume I have infinite recursion but I can't seem to find my error. Here's my code:

```
//The two sequences to compare
var sequence1 = "ATTGCTGACTTCA"
var sequence2 = "ATGCTACTA"
  //Creates multi-dimensional array dependent on sequence lengths
var arr = new Array(sequence1.length + 1)
for (i = 0; i < sequence1.length + 1; i++) {
  arr[i] = new Array(sequence2.length + 1);
}
//Fills array with 0s
for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  var col = i;
  for (i = 0; i < arr[col].length; i++) {
    arr[col][i] = 0;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you filling your array, you change the value of i by inner loop， and did not change it back to it's original value after the inner loop! Dont use the same variable name in outer and inner loops!

```
for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  var col = i;
  for (i = 0; i < arr[col].length; i++) {
    arr[col][i] = 0;
  }
  i = col;
}
```

what you realy should do:

```
for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  for (j = 0; j < arr[i].length; j++) {
    arr[i][j] = 0;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Array#from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from), [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [`Array#fill`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill).

```
var arr = Array.from({
    length: sequence1.length + 1
}).map(() => Array.from({
    length: sequence2.length + 1
}).fill(0));
```

```js
var sequence1 = "ATTGCTGACTTCA",
    sequence2 = "ATGCTACTA";

//Creates multi-dimensional array dependent on sequence lengths
var arr = Array.from({
    length: sequence1.length + 1
}).map(() => Array.from({
    length: sequence2.length + 1
}).fill(0));

console.log(arr);
```

**Explanation:**

```
var arr = Array.from({
    length: sequence1.length + 1
})
// Create an array of passed `length` of `undefined` elements

// map will iterate over all the elements of the array and update the value of each element
// Create new array and use this as the individual item in the main array
.map(() => Array.from({
    length: sequence2.length + 1
}).fill(0));
```

Comment: The outer array will be filled with the `sequence1.length + 1` references to the *same* nested array. Check the `arr[0][0] = 42; console.log(arr[1][0]);`

Comment: @zerkms Thanks for pointing. I forgot about array references. Used `map` now. :)